# split a single array based on specific inner array value

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, columnsorting

```
$data = 
          [1] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => CITY :
                            [3] => CANADA
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Customer :
                            [4] => CUS1
                        )
                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Customer :
                            [4] => CUS2
                        )
                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Customer :
                            [4] => CUS3
                        )
                   .............

                    [17] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => CITY :
                            [3] => FLORIDA
                        )

                    [18] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Customer :
                            [3] => C2
                        )
               )
```

I am trying to split an array to different arrays based on values. This is my array. I need split a single array into multiple based on inner value "CITY :"
count all "CITY :" and split array from first "CITY" to NEXT "CITY" AND NEXT....

result:
I want to split the array based on value like below

```
[1] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => CITY :
                            [3] => CANADA
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Customer :
                            [4] => CUS1
                        )
                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Customer :
                            [4] => CUS2
                        )
                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Customer :
                            [4] => CUS3
                        )
          )

 [2] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => CITY :
                            [3] => FLORIDA
                        )

                    [18] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Customer :
                            [3] => C2
                        )
```

i have no idea how to split this

Comment: can you give this array in json format? so we can try it on our end

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for you:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array(
        'CITY :',
        'CANADA'
    ),
    array(
        'Customer :',
        'CUS1'
    ),
    array(
        'Customer :',
        'CUS2'
    ),
    array(
        'Customer :',
        'CUS3'
    ),
    array(
        'CITY :',
        'FLORIDA'
    ),
    array(
        'Customer :',
        'C2'
    ),
);

$result = array();
$firstRun = true;
foreach($data as $item) {
    if(array_values($item)[0] == 'CITY :') {
        if(!$firstRun) {
            $result[] = $splittedArray;
        } else {
            $firstRun = false;
        }

        $splittedArray = array();
    }

    $splittedArray[] = $item;
}
// add last array, as it will not pass at the finish through the first logic of the loop
$result[] = $splittedArray;

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Looks good, but include some more explanation to your code. OP should understand what you are doing in the code.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas, I will add more comments to explain it next time. Here is a short explanation in order to provide more details: the code takes your data set, iterates through it, checks when "CITY :" is found and creates a new array (a split one), when the next "CITY :" is reached the code determines that a new segment starts so a new split array is created, adding the last one to the result data set.